# MIPSアセンブラを使用して書かれた整数の加算/減算を計算することができる計算機プログラムについてのmipsプログラムコードno結果が正しくない

Tags: c, assembly, mips

MIPSアセンブラを使用して書かれた整数の加算/減算を計算することができる計算機プログラムについてのmipsプログラムコードを完成しようとしている
これをデバッグするのに苦労している、結果が正しくない

入力は式の形で式char（ベースアドレス$ s0）の配列に与えられます。
 ヌル文字（¥0、ASCIIコード0）が末尾に配置されます。計算結果はレジスタ$ s1に保存され、オーバーフローは無視されます。
 例えば、入力がFormula =“ 100 + 20 + 3”の場合、$ s1 = 123、Formula =“  -  100 + 20-3”の場合、$s1 = -83が出力されます。
 プログラムの「+」と「 - 」は、それぞれASCIIの「+」と「 - 」の文字で、ASCII文字は0、１，２、３。。。9は、それぞれ　48（10）、49（10）、および57（10）です。

```
.text
.globl main

        main: 
        la $s0,word ##copy base address of array to t1
       add $s1, $zero, $zero 
        add $s2, $zero, $zero
        Addi $s3,$zero,1
        Addi $t1, $zero,'+'
        Addi $t2,$zero,'-'
        addi $t3,$zero,10

        Loop: lb $t0,0($s0)
        Addiu $s0,$s0,1 
        Beq $t0,$t1,Plus
        Beq $t0,$t2,Minus
        Beq $t0,$zero,Cal
        Addi $t0,$t0,-48 
        Mul $s2, $s2, $t3
        Add $s2,$s2,$t0
        J Loop

        End:



       li $v0,1
        move $a0,$s1
        syscall
        li $v0, 10
       syscall

          Plus: addi $s4, $zero, 1
          j Cal 
          Minus: addi $s4, $zero, 0
          Cal: beq $s3,$zero,Subn
          Addn: 

          add $s1,$s1,$s2

          beq $s4,1,Join //この部分ちょっと自信がない

          Subn: sub $s1,$s1,$s2
          Join : add $s2,$zero,$zero
          Beq $t0,$zero,End
           Add $s3,$s4,$zero
           J Loop


       Exit:
       li $v0, 10
       syscall

      .data
       word: .asciiz "-100+20+3"
        result: .asciiz "$s1->"
        prompt: .asciiz "$s0->"
```

ただし、このコードをデバッグすると出力される値が23、正しい結果は-83はずです。なぜでしょうか？

Comment: ええと、、`Subn: sub $s2,$s1,$s2` となっていますが、これは `Subn: sub $s1,$s1,$s2` ではないでしょうか(destination register は `$s2` ではなくて `$s1` かと思います )。

Comment: @metropolis そうです！！ 訂正しました、デバッグした結果　-77　です。。なぜ-83ではないでしょうか

Comment: `-100+20+3` は `-77` になりますが。。。

Comment: @metropolis ありがとうございます！！！すごくたすかりました！！！やっと正しい結果が出力されました！！　もうちょっと聞きたいことがあります、このプログラムには$s4　と　$s3 の役割なんですか（？)、あとjoin の部分も（？）

Comment: `$s3` と `$s4` には演算子(`+`, `-`)の出現状態を保存しています。それと、今気がついたのですが、コメントで「この部分ちょっと自信がない」と書かれている部分は `j Join` とすべきかと思います。計算式が `-100+20-3` の場合に間違った結果が出力されてしまいますので。`Join` ラベルの部分は `$s2` レジスタ(数値データを保存しているワークエリア)をクリア(リセット)しています。これは、次の数値データを読み込むためでしょう。

Comment: ＠metropolis ありがとうございました！！　$s2 は数値を保存するため、$s1 は演算子によって処理の結果を保存するためのレジスターである。Join は$s2にある数値をリセットする用ですね。あと$s3,$s4 は演算子の出現状態ですね！　それによって、足し算か引き算か決まる。ありがとうございました、助かりました!